# asp.net MVC published project start page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have created a an asp.net mvc web application through IIS Manager.  When I run my project locally I have set the start-page to login but when a go to the project through the website it starts in a different project page.  Do I need to change the start-page somewhere else after it is published?  Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Is it going to a page rendered by `home/index` action

Comment: Can anybody comment on a downside to changing the default route to the Account/Login Controller/Action?

Comment: My RouteConfig.cs page had controller="Home" Action="Index".  That was the problem.  Am I OK to change that to "Account" and "Login" or is there a better way?  Changing them worked though.

Comment: Yes. You can simply change that.

Comment: Good deal.. Thanks!